# X server with fglrx driver won't responce after exactly 49 accesses to X server

Tags: xorg, radeon, fglrx, gpu, amd

I have Arch linux with minimal amount of packages including xorg group and catalyst.

I run `X :0` and then run in infinity cycle following monitoring script:

```
while [ true ]; do
    DISPLAY=:0 aticonfig --odgt | grep Sensor
    sleep 1
done
```

In normal case it yield something like this:

```
              Sensor 0: Temperature - 35.00 C
              Sensor 0: Temperature - 35.00 C
              Sensor 0: Temperature - 36.00 C
```

But after exactly **49 runs** of `aticonfig` Xserver stop working. It still in processes list, I still can kill it without trouble but X isn't response to any program that is needed it. And X stop writing to log files and to stdout.

With `aticonfig` I get following error output:

```
aticonfig: This program must be run as root when no X server is active
```

It isn't necessary to run exactly `aticonfig`. Even run of any X related application decrease number of feature runs of `aticonfig`. It may be `clinfo` or any opencl application.

I reproduced such behaviour on Xorg 1.14.2 and 1.13.4, on Catalyst 13.4, 13.8.beta1, 13.8.beta2.

Xorg stdout output after Xserver start: http://pastie.org/8256590

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` after Xserver start: http://pastie.org/8256594

Xorg stdout output after each run of aticonfig: http://pastie.org/8256605

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` after each run of aticonfig:  http://pastie.org/8256608

xorg.conf is basic: http://pastie.org/8262513

So is it possible to configure o run `X` with unlimited accesses?

Answer (score 0):

X has no access limit to configure - this is not something that is supposed to happen, but instead sounds like a bug in ATI's fglrx driver.

The only limit in this area X is expected to have is a limit on the number of open client connections - that's not configurable without recompiling the source code today, but patches have been proposed to allow an option to configure at runtime.  But once a program closes its connection and exits, that frees its slot for the next program, so doesn't match your description.